# How to use PayPal Giving Fund with giving a Tip to another account

Tags: paypal

On my website, I want to use PayPal Giving Fund with an option for donors to give a Tip. This Tip will go to another PayPal account.

On the same web page there will be 
- the contribution to the PayPal Giving Fund 
- optional Tip (which goes to another PayPal account)

These contributions would be seamless to the donor and would not have to go to PayPal.

The donor will receive two PayPal confirmation emails...
one from the PayPal Giving Fund
one from the PayPal account for the Tip

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Giving Fund doesn't support split payments, so far as I can tell.

There is an old classic API that supports split payments, called Express Checkout Parallel Payments: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/express-checkout/ht-ec-parallelPayments/

I don't necessarily recommend integrating that, but it is the only generally-available PayPal API I'm aware of that allows splitting a payment in a single checkout.  Anything else, you'd have to contact PayPal about.